# 'bundle install' error for gems using git path Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, bundler

Every time I deploy to my production server I get the following error for gems that use a git path:

```
git://github.com/odorcicd/example.git (at rails3) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::PathError)
```

I've found that if I run "bundle install --deployment" it solves this problem.  But it installs all my gems again and I have to do it after each deployment.  Has anyone found a better solution than this?

This is an example of the using a git path in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'efax', :git => 'https://github.com/TTDaVeTT/efax.git'
```

Comment: usually, I use `:git => "git://github.com/foo_bar.git` no http url

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here: I've got this gem that requires a git origin.

```
gem "machinist_mongo", :git => "https://github.com/nmerouze/machinist_mongo.git", :require => "machinist/mongoid", :branch => "machinist2"
```

From what I've found; `bundle` installs the gem, but not in your gemset - so you have to get rails to include the gems specifically somehow... need help on that part.